# R function to return the license of a package?

Tags: r, metadata

I'd like to return the package license as declared in the DESCRIPTION file of an R package (ideally I'd rather have the URL that CRAN automatically adds to all the common licenses it recognizes).

I realize I can get the license R itself is distributed under with

```
license()
```

which amazingly doesn't apply to packages; e.g. license("packagename")

Nor is this data returned by a call to `citation("packagename")`.

Comment: Wow, the `license` function is just a sequence of `cat` functions that spits the license info out. Is that built from a license file at some point or is it all hardcoded in there in the source? Yuck. Anyway, maybe R-core would like an addition to that so you could do `license(package="foo")`....

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you are looking for `packageDescription`

eg:

```
packageDescription("stats", fields="License")
[1] "Part of R 2.15.3"

packageDescription("ggplot2", fields="License")
[1] "GPL-2"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get the licenses for all installed packages, then use the `installed.packages` command.

Borrowing from the help page for this command:

```
lisc <- installed.packages(fields = "License")
```

To output the licenses to a csv file:

```
write.csv(lisc[,c(1,10)], "RPackageLicenses.csv")
```