# How to view package license file?

Tags: r, licensing, r-package

I have a package called `my_pkg` and in my `DESCRIPTION` file I've declared my license as `License: file LICENSE`.

[Another question suggested using `packageDescription` to call the license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508822/r-function-to-return-the-license-of-a-package), but that yields the following:

```
> packageDescription('my_pkg', fields = 'License')
"file LICENSE"
```

Any ideas how to proceed? I've checked [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Licensing) and [Hadley's R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#license) to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
file.show(system.file("LICENSE",package="my_pkg"))
```

should work (it works for the `ggalt` package).  It won't work if there is no `LICENSE` file, of course ...